# Action mailer not sending/receiving email rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, actionmailer

I'm trying to create a simple blog (using rails 5) and want to send email updates when to users when I post something new. I'm trying to use actionmailer and I'm using devise to register users. I'm trying to set it up with just the first user initially.

When I look at my local server the email appears to be sending but it's not received. Any advice would be very welcome I've been stuck a while.

```
    UserNotifierMailer#sample_email: processed outbound mail in 410.4ms
Sent mail to myemail@gmail.com (853.2ms)
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 12:05:33 +0100
From: from@example.com
To:myemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5798957d9de31_ae813ff962abfe1466438@Unknown-7c-d1-c3-78-04-d2.home.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5798957d951e2_ae813ff962abfe1466312";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

My posts controller looks like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.first
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
      UserNotifierMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

My mailer looks like this:

```
class UserNotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "from@example.com"
  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://www.google.com'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
  end
end
```

and in my development.rb I have these settings:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "my_gmail_username",
    password: "my_gmail_password"
  }
```

Comment: Try changing this feature on on your google account(not sure if it will help): https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I've finally got it working, it was to do with google 2 step verification. Make sure it's turned OFF!

Answer (score 4):

In your configured  Gmail account:

1. Go to  <kbd>Account Settings</kbd> Than
2. Go to <kbd>Sign-in & security</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Connected apps & sites</kbd>
3. At last in <kbd>Allow less secure apps</kbd> ... Check it.

Check Once And Try

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
> config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
> ...
> config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
> ```

I don't config any of the above and it still works.

> ```
> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
> ```

and have to `.deliver_later` or `.deliver_now`, `.deliver` not work

Comment: I've wrapped the code above in blockquotes since you seem to be referring to code in the question. If this is incorrect, you can unroll the changes from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40966354/revisions) or [edit] the post to make further improvements. I have no idea what the last sentence means, though.